# sinusoidal signal, computing its power

Tags: power, circuit-analysis

I have a book which is giving a brief solution to a theoretical question, it is skipping some steps of the solution,these missed steps seems to be important to me to understand them.I recite them below and i would like some help for a more detailed solution without skipping steps.

**Question 1:**
$$given\,\,x(t)= Acos(ω_0t+θ),\,\,\, T_0=\frac{2π}{ω_0}\,compute\,its\,power.$$
$$
\begin{align}
P &= \frac{1}{T_o}\int_0^{T_o} [x(t)]^2dt\\ \\
&=\,\,\frac{ω_0}{2π}\int_0^{\frac{2π}{ω_0}}A^2cos^2(ω_0t+θ)dt\\ \\
&=\,\,\frac{A^2ω_0}{2π}\int_0^{\frac{2π}{ω_0}}\frac{1}2[1+cos(2ω_0t+2θ)]dt\\
&=\,\,<missing\, steps\, start\, from\, here\, that\, i\, need\,them\, to\, be\, filled>\\
&=\frac{A^2}{2}\\
\end{align}
$$
i can proceed with the missing steps up to a certain point as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
&=\,\,\frac{A^2ω_0}{2π}\frac12\Bigl(\int_0^{\frac{2π}{ω_0}}dt+\int_0^{\frac{2π}{ω_0}}cos(2ω_0t+2θ)] \,dt\,\Bigr)\\
&=\,\,\frac{A^2}{2}\frac{ω_0}{2π}\,\Bigl(\,t\vert_0^\frac{2π}{ω_0}+\frac{1}{2ω_0}\,sin(2ω_0t+2θ)\vert_0^\frac{2π}{ω_0}\,\Bigr)\\
&=\,\,\frac{A^2}{2}\frac{ω_0}{2π}\,\Bigl(\,\frac{2π}{ω_0}+\frac{1}{2ω_0}\,sin(2ω_0\frac{2π}{ω_0}+2θ)\,\Bigr)\\
&=\,\,\frac{A^2}{2}\,\Bigl(\,\frac{ω_0}{2π}\frac{2π}{ω_0}+\frac{ω_0}{2π}\frac{1}{2ω_0}\,sin(2\cdot2π+2θ)\,\Bigr)\\
&=\,\,\frac{A^2}{2}\,\Bigl(\,1+\frac{1}{4π}\,sin(4π+2θ)\,\Bigr)\\
&=\,\,\frac{A^2}{2}\,\Bigl(\,1+\frac{1}{4π}\,????\,\Bigr)\\
&=??
\end{align}
$$
Looking at sin(4π+2θ), i know that sin(4π)=0 and that would have given the solution, but it has an additional term,which is 2θ and the book says nothing extra about θ. Maybe, i might have made a mistake or two in my **incomplete** solution.

**Question 2:**

If i integrate with respect to ωt instead of just t,how do i justify,explain this conversion? Also, what is the point of working with respect to ωt instead of just t?

(It seems that somehow t is multiplied by ω and also To is multiplied by ω. Thus, ωTo=2π. That is my best guess,although i do not fully comprehend why it would work if it is a correct guess).
$$P = \frac{1}{T_o}\int_0^{T_o} [x(t)]^2dt=\frac{1}{2π}\int_0^{2π}(x(ωt))^2\,d(ωt)$$

Comment: In the third step you have not carried out the other limit of integration at t=0. If you do this both sine terms will cancel out and you get A^2/2 as the answer.

Comment: but that would give sin(0+theta) which does not make sense, or i still cannot see my mistake

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not specifically about EE and is more suited to maths stack exchange.

Comment: @Andy and what should i do? ask again the same thing in math stack?

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything really other than learn for next time!

Comment: The average value of an unbiased sinusoid over a complete cycle is zero, regardless of the constant phase angle (theta in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start from:

\$\frac{A^2ω_0}{2π}\int_0^{\frac{2π}{ω_0}}\frac{1}2[1+cos(2ω_0t+2θ)]dt\$

Extract the 1/2 out of the integral, you get

\$ \frac{A^2ω_0}{2π} \frac12 \frac{2π}{ω_0} 
+ \frac{A^2ω_0}{2π} \int_0^{\frac{2π}{ω_0}}cos(2ω_0t+2θ) \,dt\$

The one on the left is \$ \frac{A^2}{2} \$ and the one on the right is 0 since the cos is integrated over a full period. The mistake is on your third line, because this:

\$ sin(2ω_0t+2θ)\vert_0^\frac{2π}{ω_0}\$

...expands to:

\$ sin(2ω_0\frac{2π}{ω_0}+2θ) - sin(2θ) = sin(4π+2θ) - sin(2θ)\$

(you forgot one of the two) and \$ sin( whatever + 4π ) \$ is equal to \$ sin( whatever ) \$ ...

so this part is zero and you only keep \$ \frac{A^2}{2} \$.

Comment: thank you for answering my question 1. I see my mistake. Do you know the answer for my question 2? If you do not understand what i am asking in question 2 i can explain more.

Comment: It's an application of a [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_single_variable) for substitution of the integration variable

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that solving this algebraically is missing the point: -

[image]

So, if you have a sine or cosine waveform with peak amplitude A, the mean-squared value for this waveform is \$\dfrac{A^2}{2}\$.

Why do a bunch of math that might cause you to miss the simplicity of just thinking about it and understanding it?

Just so that the math folk are catered for, from Proofs of trigonometric identities (see Wikipedia): -

[image]

If you square a sine or cosine wave you get a DC level with a "twice frequency" component superimposed (as per my diagram at the top).

Comment: Elegantly simple. +1